# Unsigned long back into pointer to a class

Tags: c++

Now, I am doing a exercise in introduction to algorithms by using C++. 
The question is :

> Explain how to implement doubly linked lists using only one pointer
>   value x.np per item instead of the usual two (next and prev). Assume
>   that all pointer values can be interpreted as k-bit integers, and
>   define x.np = x.next XOR x.prev, the k-bit "exclusive-or" of x.next
>   and x.prev. (The value NIL is represented by 0). Be sure to describe
>   what information you need to access the head of the list. Show how to
>   implement the SEARCH, INSERT and DELETE operations on such a list.
>   Also show how to reverse such a list in O(1) time.

In the XOR function, I first convert pointer to class into unsigned long and Xor these two value. And then convert the result back to a pointer to class. I don't know why it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
struct node
{
int key;

node *np;
} ;

struct list_n
{
node *head;

node *tail;
};
```

The above are two structs and below is insertion

```
void insert_element(list_n *_list, int _key)
{
    node *present_node= new node;

    present_node->key=_key;

    present_node->np=xor_gate(nullptr,_list->tail);

    if(_list->tail) _list-> tail->np=xor_gate(present_node,xor_gate(nullptr,_list->tail->np ));

    if(!_list->head) _list->head=present_node;

    _list->tail=present_node;
}
```

Below is the Xor gate :

```
node *xor_gate(node *left,node *right)
{
    unsigned long result;

    result =  ( reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(left) ) ^  ( reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(right) );

    node *output =new node;

    output = reinterpret_cast<node*> (result);  // yes or no

    return output ;
}


void list_n_inti(list_n *a )
{
    a->head =nullptr;

    a->tail =nullptr;
}
```

I have review the code several times. I think the problem is caused by XOR gate.

If you have found the bug please tell me. And if you have any other ways to answer this question. please tell me.

Thank you

Comment: The size of unsigned long main or may not match the size of pointer, there is `::std::uintptr_t` integer type that can hold ptr value. `output` in your `xor_gate` is initialized with newly allocated `node` instance, but you immediately overwrite it with another value so memory leaks. In c++ you perform initialization using constructors, functions like `list_n_inti` typically indicate a smelly code...

Comment: `node *output =new node; output = reinterpret_cast<node*>(result);` the second statement overwrites the value stored by the first and the pointer given by `new node` is gone.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I have changed my code as you mentioned. but I still has one error that is in this line                                         
    present_node->np=xor_gate(nullptr,_list->tail);   if I change the second the input to nullptr, this program will work. I don't know why that happen.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the bug.

Answer (score 1):

There is a memory leak in `xor_gate`, but I think the code works if you compile it as 32-bits. If you compile it as 64-bits, then `unsigned long` cannot contain a pointer generally.

try this:

```
#include <cstdint>  // for uintptr_t

node *xor_gate(node *left,node *right)
{
    using std::uintptr_t;

    uintptr_t result =  ( reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(left) ) ^  ( reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(right) );

    return reinterpret_cast<node*> (result);
}
```